# Fade In on image swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i´m using this script to swap image when click on a thumbnail:

```
$("#thumbs a").click( function() {
    var changeSrc = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#target").attr("src", changeSrc);
    return false;
});
```

How can I make the changeSrc action to be like a smooth fadeOut and fadeIn of the other image?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ and http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
$("#thumbs a").on('click', function() {
    var href = this.href;
    $("#target").fadeOut(600, function() {
        $(this).attr('src', href).fadeIn(600);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$("#target").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).attr("src", changeSrc).fadeIn('slow');
});
```